# AWS CDK Lambda Layer ARN lookup - Parameter and Secrets Lambda Extension

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add a layer to my Lambda function in Python CDK and its working, but, I always have to specify the ARN and at the moment I have the layer's ARN us-east-1,

```py
layers=[LayerVersion.from_layer_version_arn(
            "AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension-Layer-ARM64",
            "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:177933569100:layer:AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension-Arm64:2")
       ],
```

The problem is, if I want to deploy the code in a pipeline that's in a different region, I will have to code each layer ARN region by region which is not the best idea, is there a way for me to just pass in the the name of the layer `AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension-Arm64` and the CDK can look up automatically the ARN where the deployment is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but there is an open CDK [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/23187) to add tailored support for the AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension.

In the meantime, you can use language features to build the [layer ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ps-integration-lambda-extensions.html#ps-integration-lambda-extensions-add) from the stack environment context at synth-time:

```py
# my_stack.py constructor

region = self.region
arm_arns = {"us-east-1": "177933569100", "eu-central-1": "187925254637"}
account = arm_arns[region]

layer_arn = self.format_arn(
    account=account,
    service="lambda",
    resource="layer",
    resource_name="AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension-Arm64:2",
    arn_format=ArnFormat.COLON_RESOURCE_NAME,
)
```

Your pipeline stacks must have an explicitly set region value for this approach to work.